# Send a message to a specific ID python-telegram-bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I would like to send a message to the mantainer of the bot (specific ID) whenever it initializes. All the script was made with handlers, and I can't make it work with both methods of sending messages:

```
def main() -> None:
    """Start the bot."""
    # Create the Application and pass it your bot's token.
    application = Application.builder().token("TOKEN").build()
    
    application.bot.send_message("SOME ID","Hello! I am working.") # Problematic line

    # Handlers
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler("command", command_function))
    ...
    
    # on non command i.e message - echo the message on Telegram
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND, default_command))
    
    # Run the bot until the user presses Ctrl-C
    application.run_polling()
```

If I try to run the previous script, I get the following warning:

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'ExtBot.send_message' was never awaited
  application.bot.send_message("SOME ID","Hello! I am working.") # Problematic line
```

I can guess that the problem is between both methods of sending messages. But is there any way I can use both at the same time? (Or at least once, only when the bot initializes)

Comment: Do you run this using asyncio? Than you could just let asyncio handle it.

Answer (score 1):

To run asyncio-code on startup, the `Application(Builder)` class provides the [`post_init`](https://docs.python-telegram-bot.org/en/stable/telegram.ext.applicationbuilder.html#telegram.ext.ApplicationBuilder.post_init) hook. The documentation also includes an example of how to use this hook to call bot methods on startup.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currentyl the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`